# Replacing oil cooler lines on 2017 Chevy Silverado 5.3L

Tags: chevrolet, oil-leak, silverado, parts-replacement

The oil cooler lines are leaking on my son's 2017 Chevy Silverado 5.3L, so I need to replace them. The space the lines run through on the driver side of the engine is very tight.  Has anyone done this and can recommend the best approach.

Comment: I'd have to look at my 2018 Silverado ... might do that later. Even if it is tight, I'd think it would probably be fairly straight forward. I would think they just run straight forward and up to the radiator area. Once they are removed at the ends, there probably aren't too many things holding them on at that point. If I can ask, what's going on that the lines are leaking (in case I need to look out for this on my truck)?

Comment: The cooler lines are leaking where the metal meets the rubber which can been seen looking from the front of the truck down to where the lines connect to the radiator. I think these have a crimp joint.  This is a common leak point on these types of metal/rubber cooler lines.  His tranny cooler lines are leaking too, same type of metal/rubber lines, but those have more space to remove and replace the lines. If you have any advice after looking at your 2018 please let me know.  Thank you Paulster2!

Comment: I went outside to look and found ... it's raining, lol. I lifted the hood, but really didn't want to crawl under it. Are the lines you are talking about coming from the driver's side and cross over to the passenger side? Or are those the tranny lines? After looking, I'm wondering if I actually have oil cooler lines, lol. Mainly because I can't account for extra lines. All I'm seeing are these two and the AC lines which come forward to the radiator (around the radiator in the case of the AC lines).

Comment: Correct - they cross over to the passenger side and connect to the radiator.  There are two sets of lines on my son's truck.  The larger diameter lines are the oil cooler and the smaller diameter are the tranny lines.  The bugger of getting them out is down by the tranny. Very tight space. No need to crawl on the ground and get wet and dirty.  A mechanic friend said it is easier to drop the subframe to get a bit more space.  I don't want to do this if I don't have to, henceforth my question.

Comment: If the lines are leaking right where the rubber meets the metal lines up in front right behind the radiator, have you considered just taking the crimp cap (don't know what to call it) and replacing it with a hose clamp?

Comment: I don't think that would work for this application given how the lines are crimped.  Thank you for the thought though..

Comment: Actually, seriously, I'd try this first. Looking at mine, you can cut the crimped part off and put a clamp on in it's place. Think of the crimped part as a permanent clamp. I've done this before to other crimped lines. It would be a heck of a lot easier than replacing the lines. You just have to split the cap to get it off there. It shouldn't be "connected" at the back, even though it looks like it.

Comment: That makes sense.  I will give it a shot.  Thank you for your advice Paulster2!